# Does there exist a version of the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality for multidimensional continuous local martingales?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0},\mathbb{P})$ be a stochastic basis and $M$ a continuous local martingale on it with start in $0$. Then the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality states that for all $p>0$ there exists some $C_p>0$ s.t.
$$
\mathbb{E}[\sup_{s \leq t}|M_s|^p] \leq C_p\mathbb{E}[\langle M\rangle_t ^{\frac{p}{2}} ]
$$

holds for all $t \geq 0$.

If $M$ is multidimensional(i.e. every component is a continuous local martingale starting in $0$), does

$$
\mathbb{E}[\sup_{s \leq t}\|M_s\|_p^p] \leq C_p\mathbb{E}[\|\langle M\rangle_t \|_p^{\frac{p}{2}} ]
$$

hold? It would be very useful to me but I can not find this anywhere and I was not able to proof it. I would be grateful for a reference or any hint.

Comment: A reference here : https://bibos.math.uni-bielefeld.de/preprints/13-08-451.pdf for the case of a Hilbert spacesvalued local martingales. As Euclidian spaces $R^n$ are Hilbert  equiped with the classical scalar product this should do the trick right ?

Comment: No problem at all. For example, you can estimate $\sup_s ||M_s||^p \le C_p \sum_{i=1}^d \sup_s|M_s^i|^p$ and use the scalar BDG.